# ¿Cómo puedo colocar dos curvas una encima de la otra, para dos curvas con diferentes valores en python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hola tengo el siguiente código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_1 = [1,3,5,7,9,10]

y_1 = [6,9,12,15,18,21]

x_2 = [-6,-4,-2,0,2,3]

y_2 = [-1,2,5,8,11,14]

plt.plot(x_1,y_1,marker='*',color='darkred',linestyle='--')

plt.plot(x_2,y_2,marker='+',color='darkblue',linestyle='-.')

plt.show()
```

En el código estan superpuestos uno arriba y otro abajo, quisiera superponerlos los uno encima del otro  (o sea que se vea una sola curva ) ¿hay una forma?, quizá se podría usar un twinx().

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Rocker! No entiendo que quieres decir con "al mismo nivel", si tienes datos númericos distintos, van a estar a distinto nivel cuando estén en una gráfica. Si puedes subir una  foto/dibujo con el resultado esperado por favor.

Comment: @Rubiales Alberto quiero poner una encima de la otra

Comment: Vale, si es eso, creo que mi respuesta te puede valer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final una gráfica está compuesta de un eje "X" y un eje "Y".

- Eje X (abscisas): es el encargado de la continuidad de la gráfica, es decir, de gráficar de izquierda a derecha.
- Eje y (ordenadas): es el engargado de la altura de la gráfica, es decir, de gráficar más arriba o abajo.

Con esta información, si lo que quieres es superponer dos lineas, significa que quieres **quedar el eje de abscisas en el mismo sitio, y mover el eje de ordenadas**, así las lineas estarán más arriba o más abajo.

Podemos mover el eje de ordenadas sumando o restando un parámetro que podemos llamar `alpha`, te dejo una función.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x_1 = [1,3,5,7,9,10]
y_1 = [6,9,12,15,18,21]

#Creo esta función por si se le entrega una lista, pasar a array
def validar_tipo(x):
    return np.array(x) if type(x) == list else x

#Función que superpone lineas en una gráfica
def superponer_plot(x, y, alpha=5):
    #Validamos que sean arrays
    x = validar_tipo(x)
    y = validar_tipo(y)
    
    #Queremos mover el eje y, luego sumamos un escalar al array
    y_2 = y + alpha

    #Mostramos el gráfico
    plt.plot(x, y, marker='*',color='darkred',linestyle='--')
    plt.plot(x, y_2, marker='+',color='darkblue',linestyle='-.')
    plt.show()

#Ejecutamos la función 
superponer_plot(x_1, y_1, 4)
```

He hecho lo siguiente:

- He creado la función `validar_tipo()` que actuara dentro de la función `superponer_plot()` ya que necesitamos un array, lo que hará será convertir nuestra lista a un vector en el caso de que no le pasemos un vector **para poderle sumar un escalar** (un número cualquiera).
- La función `superponer_plot()` lo que hace es quedar para ambos plot, el mismo eje de abscisas (x) y mover el eje de ordenadas (y) en base a un parámetro que le pasamos llamado `alpha`. De esta forma podemos superponer una gráfica a la distancia que queramos una de la otra sumandole al eje *Y* un escalar `alpha`

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Nota

Recalcar que cuando dices *"con diferentes valores"*, los valores diferentes que puedes modificar es solo el eje de ordenadas (y), ya que si modficas el eje de abscisas (x), nunca te van a quedar una encima de otra, **eso es imposible.**

Comment: muchas gracias me ha servido